# How many Maiar are there?

Tags: the-lord-of-the-rings, tolkiens-legendarium, the-silmarillion

Iluvitar made 2 classes of spirit beings to sing the songs of creation. The higher class (more powerful) are the Valar who are 15 in number, the lower class (less powerful) are the Maiar. I can find the names of about 15 or so Maia but the stories seem to indicate there are many more than just 15 of them. How many Maiar did Iluvitar make? Dozens? Hundreds? Thousands?

Comment: When Iluvitar made these beings there was no distinction. They were all called Ainur (Not sure that that is the right word). When some entered the world the 15 most powerful were called Valar. The others were called Maiar and there were many of them. At least a twice as many as the valar are mentioned specifically but I believe there are many more.

Comment: @Bellerophon Tolkien is actually inconsistent about that. Sometimes the Valar are _all of the Ainur who entered Arda_, sometimes it's just the dozen or so mist powerful.

Comment: @Spencer presumably this is in line with many other changes with associated inconsistencies that he made. In the BoLT, iirc, the characters that were later Maiar were instead referred to as the 'children of the Valar', and I suspect they only arrived once everyone was in Arda.

Comment: @DanielRoberts It's inconsistent even within the published _Silmarillion_.

Answer (score 5):

### Total

Not known; Tolkien himself wrote that the Elves didn't know how many (emphasis mine):

> With the Valar came other spirits whose being also began before the World, of the same order as the Valar but of less degree. These are the Maiar, the people of the Valar, and their servants and helpers. **Their number is not known to the Elves**, and few have names in any of the tongues of the Children of Ilúvatar; for though it is otherwise in Aman, in Middle-earth the Maiar have seldom appeared in form visible to Elves and Men.
>
> <sup>*The Silmarillion* II *Valaquenta* "Of the Maiar"</sup>

I don't know of any writings where Tolkien gives an estimate, so this is what we have.

### Known

A bunch; at least fourteen or fifteen named:

- Sauron
- The five Istari
- Eönwë, herald of Manwë
- Ilmarë, handmaid of Varda
- Ossë, vassal of Ulmo and Uinen, his wife
- Salmar, of Ulmo
- Melian
- Arien, the Sun
- Tilion, the Moon
- The balrogs, of whom there were [either seven or "a lot"](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/55899/how-many-balrogs-were-there)
- [Probably Huan](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/93203/what-happened-to-huan-the-wolfhound-after-he-died)
- Some number who became orcs, some of whom [may or may not have been called Boldog](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/108592/are-there-orcs-who-were-well-known-before-becoming-one/)

And possibly any number of other creatures; it's a fairly common assertion among Tolkien fans that any speaking creature that isn't a Vala, Man (or Hobbit), Elf, Dwarf, or Orcish is necessarily a Maia; that would include (but is not necessarily limited to):

- The Ents
- [The Eagles](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/53935/what-is-the-origin-of-the-great-eagles)
- [The Dragons](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/103881/who-gave-life-to-the-dragons-of-middle-earth)
- Draugluin the Werewolf and his brood (including Carcharoth)
- [The Vampires](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/89891/vampires-in-middle-earth), including Thuringwethil
- [Tom Bombadil](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/1586/who-or-what-was-tom-bombadil/) and Goldberry
- [Ungoliant and her brood (including Shelob)](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/54890/is-shelob-a-maia)

Comment: I would say that Balrogs were either *three* or a lot.

Comment: If 14 or 15 are named, and "few have names," then the total count should be at least 150ish, even if none of those creatures in the last list were Maiar. So that would be a lower bound.

Comment: @ibid seven is the lower number as this is written somewhere, I think in one of the Christopher Tolkien edited books

Comment: @CearonO'Flynn - *There should not be supposed more than say 3 or at most 7 ever existed.* - margin note to The Annals of Aman, (Morgoth's Ring - HoME-X, Section 2)

Comment: Maybe this is a separate question but r u sure the Ents are Maia?

Comment: @turinsbane Not remotely, and that was precisely my point.

Comment: I don't think there's ever even a suggestion that Ents are Maiar. They're the same "level" of being as Dwarves.

Comment: @OrangeDog If the Ents are not Maiar, then when did Iluvatar give them life as he did for elves, dwarves and men? No Valar can do so, which is why Aule had to get Iluvatar to five lode to the dwarves he had created.

Comment: @MikeScott when Yavanna asked Him to. I don't have the text to hand to be more specific right now

Comment: In the speculative section, Old Man Willow, also the River Withywindle.

Comment: @Spencer Surely Old Man Willow is a huorn, and the Withywindle is Goldberry.

Comment: @MikeScott Eh. Old Man Willow _may be_ a Huorn, or an Elf whose _hroa_ burned away and whose _fëa_ took up residence in a tree, but it's never confirmed, thus he goes in the speculative section. Goldberry is the _daughter_ of Withywindle.